# Does porttalk work in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, drivers, port, io, elevation

[Porttalk](https://retired.beyondlogic.org/porttalk/porttalk.htm) is a driver that enables applications to access hardware's I/Os directly, like it was possible in Windows 98. Porttalk consists basically of two files:

`porttalk.sys`: The actual driver

`allowio.exe`: Application which takes another application.exe and I/O adresses as parameter and enables it to access them directly.

Example call:

```
allowio.exe 0x300 0x310 beep.exe
```

This would start `beep.exe` and enable it to access I/O address 0x300 to 0x310 directly.

I know that porttalk worked in Windows XP. Now I need to port an application to Windows 10 but the application seems unable to access the addresses directly. I could not find any confirmation that porttalk won't work in Windows 10.

Is porttalk (or similar drivers) still compatible with Windows 10? I could imagine that Windows 10 prohibited the possiblity of directly accessing hardware I/Os completely in order to increase security.

Comment: http://semantic.gs/porttalk_driver_v2_download claims it works with Windows 10.

Comment: @DavidPostill this looks like a scam website to be honset.

Comment: {shrug} when downloading/instaling anything you should take appropriate precautions

Comment: @DavidPostill Why not double check suspicious websites before posting them? That'd help too.

Answer (score -1):

PORTTALK Driver,
 http://semantic.gs/porttalk_driver_v2_download

To install follow this like,
 https://www.qsl.net/dl4yhf/winpic/install_porttalk.htm